# git staging server

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, staging

We are working on setting up a git environment, and for our workflow, we would like to do the following:

[image]

The issue is that I want to be able to easily pick and choose which changes I want to push to production from staging. For example, if dev1 is working on feature 1 and dev2 is working on feature 2, I might only want to push the changes of feature 1 to production. Is this possible? I might even have a case where dev1 is working on feature 3 and feature 4, but I only want to push feature 4 to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common. I do this frequently.

The approach to use is to have developers create what are called *feature branches* (or just *branches*.

This is done using the command:

```
git checkout -b my_new_feature
```

Then they can work on the feature and everyone else can get that code, but it won't mix with any other branches until that branch is *merged* into your master branch, like so:

```
git checkout master
git merge my_new_feature
```

Different developers can work on different features however long it takes, then you can merge to master (and push to staging) whenever it makes sense.

Comment: would these feature branches be on the server or local to a developer?

Comment: Both. Git *synchronizes* everyone's repositories. You can all share exact copies of everyone's work. It has tools to handle merging and resolving conflicts. You'll never have to check a file out to make a change.

Comment: So when I do a git checkout -b my_new_feature, the server (gitolite in our case) will maintain a copy of that branch as well?

Comment: It will *if* you push that branch to the server. You *may* choose to keep a branch local to your machine, but most commonly a branch intended to hold a new feature is pushed to the central server and shared by other team members.

Comment: Then would you recommend pushing from the feature branch directly to master? Or have a staging branch in between to ensure everything is healthy before pushing into the master?

Comment: I've seen both work. It really depends on how formal you want your process, if you have a QA team, etc. It's becoming more common now to minimize branching and keep `master` as close to current as possible -- but that doesn't work for everyone. Pick the approach that seems like it will fit your existing process best and just start there. You can add a staging branch easily if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Thanks. In that article though, he suggests merging feature branches back into the "develop" branch. Can I then easily pick and choose which of those commits end up in production?

Comment: @JeffStorey Exactly the method - you pick the when any why you want to merge feature X into production. Of course there will be issues with F5 relies on F4 - but hey its a RCS not a magician ;-)

Comment: @JeffStorey Oh and if you want to go nuts -gerrit and help with the link between commits that rely on each other.

Comment: So I'm still somewhat new to git, but basically if several features were merged from feature branches into the staging area, then it is still easy to choose which of those features to merge to production?

Comment: Also, as for gerrit, we've looked into that, but we're currently using Atlassian Crucible for reviews and would like to continue using that.

Comment: @JeffStorey I still consider myself new to git - even though I've spent the last 18months converting company repos etc and testing different things. I tried gerrit - I liked the workflow - no real world exp with it. All are stuff is still CVS so I do nightly imports into go for my personal use. git rebase -i seems to be what you want - but I suggest you play with it because I find it not at all intuitive and make mistakes - so I recommend a test branch

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the input.

Comment: np @JeffStorey - if I can help bung me an email at stackoverflow at bluedreamer.com

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest for each developer to maintain their own branch, which they are responsible for keeping updated to current versions of your master branch.  Or even one branch per "feature that is a distinct merge candidate".  Then you, as owner of the production branch, get to choose which branches to merge, and when.  Having everyone pushing into a shared staging tree which you **dont** use a simple one-way stage on the way to production sounds like a recipe for mistakes.

Comment: in the "one branch per feature" model, would that mean there would be a feature branch on the server for each feature that then gets merged into production when ready? And the shared staging area would be eliminated?